# is it possible to store two items in a single react context or do you have to use a map?

Tags: reactjs

is it possible to store two items in a single react context or do you have to use a map?

```
export const id = 0 ;
export const name = '' ;
export const RecordContext = React.createContext( id, name );
```

Comment: You can put it in an object If that's what you meant by map, then yea that

Answer (score 1):

Context can only be a single object/value.  See [React.createContext documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext).  If you want to include multiple primitive values, use an object like `{id: 0, name: ''}` (preferred) or an array like `[0, '']`.